# Angular 6 Project: "task.downloadURL()" missing?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am very new to programming in general and in the last few weeks, I have been following along several tutorials of Angular applications from YouTube videos. Right now, I was building a blog according to the instructions of this video:

https://youtu.be/Rpe8s4-qFFI?t=5187 (pause exactly at the timestamp to 'see' my problem)

Up until now, everything has worked. My code is exactly like his code, but for some reason i do not have the option to choose the `"downloadURL()"` method as he has done.

[image: Screenshot of my project]

I have checked several times if  i had forgotten anything. 
Here is the code of the project that he wrote: [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/foli/ng-blog/blob/master/src/app/posts/post-dashboard/post-dashboard.component.ts)

This is the component that causes trouble for me. As I said, my code looks exactly like his. The last two hours, i was looking for an answer but could not find anything, which is why i decided to ask here.

I apologize in advance if this may be dumb or if i need to attach more information about my code in here. If so, i will upload mine as well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should add your code here and not a screen shot - people won't want to type it all out to help you test

Comment: Your constructor code is not in the screenshot. Confirm that the storage is of type AngularFireStorage.

`private storage: AngularFireStorage`

Comment: I see. I am sorry, I will attach my code in future questions. This time, i was just sure that it doesn't really matter because it is 1:1 the same code as in the GitHub link and i thought it may be a problem with some newer versions of anything i used in the tutorial. 

But I see your points and will add in the future anyway, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `task.downloadURL()` method has been removed in favor of `ref.getDownloadURL()`. From this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1649):

```
this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() // And this one to actually grab the URL from the Ref
```

Or (since you don't seem to track your `fileRef` yet:

```
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = this.storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL() )
 )
.subscribe()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this and the GitHub issue. My problem just got solved. Next time I will try looking for an answer on GitHub issues more.